# bitmap image displays black on imageview in xamarin

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, xamarin

I have an ImageView on my screen and all I am trying to do is Display an image in it. All i am getting is a black screen displaying where the photo is supposed to

```
    ImageView Display = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Photo);

    File dir = new File(
    Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "Photo's");

    Display.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(dir.AbsolutePath + "/Photo.jpg"));
```

All smaller jpeg images display's with

```
     Display.SetImageURI(data.Data);
```

where data is the intent from the OnActivityResult
it seems like the problem is not image file size orientated but actual pixel count orientated but I am very unsure.

Comment: are you *sure* the path you're using is correct?

Comment: Yes, the path i am using is not static... it is retrieved from the folder created with the same directory path.

Comment: do you have the proper read permissions? are you sure Photos.jpg isn't a black jpeg?

Comment: I have tried multiple different photos and permisions is something i have not yet looked at, but i am pretty convinced this is not the issue. i have edited again with some more information

Comment: @Neil Did you find a solution ? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Erzékiel Sadly not. I moved away from xamarin because I ran into to many problems that seemed like bugs, For this scenario i ended up reducing the image pixel count to a certain amount, it seemed to work most of the time. sorry man